# [typescript]Create a class that can be called directly without new

Tags: typescript

Create a class that can be called directly without new

```
class View {
    constructor() {
    }
}
new View();
View()
```

Similar to this

```
new String("")
String("")
```

How can I do this?

Comment: TypeScript is just a superset of JavaScript, which means you can just define class in the good old ES5 way (You can not call ES6 class constructor without new too).

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is what's known as a factory function

https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1

```
class View{
    constructor(){
    }

    static makeView() {
        return new View();
    }
}
const view1 = new View();
const view2 = makeView();
```

I don't think you can call it the exact same thing as your class though.